# Find the points on the line containing the points $(1,0,5)$ and $(3,1,-2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the first year linear algebra question. 
Which of the following points is on the line containing the points $(1,0,5)$ and $(3,1,-2)$?

a). $( 0,-3,17)$

b). $(9,4,-23)$

c). $(-9,-4,23)$

d). $(0,3,-17)$

e). $(-1,-1,-12)$

The answer is b).

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html

Answer (score 3):

The line $L$ through the points $(1,0,5)$ and $(3,1,-2)$ is parallel to the line $L'$ through the origin and

$$(3,1,-2)-(1,0,5)=(2,1,-7)\;.$$

Because it does pass through the origin, $L'$ is just the set of scalar multiples of $(2,0,-7)$, i.e.,

$$L'=\big\{t(2,1,-7):t\in\Bbb R\big\}\;.$$

$L$ is parallel to this and passes through $(1,0,5)$, so it’s just $L'$ shifted by $(1,0,5)$:

$$L=\big\{(1,0,5)+t(2,1,-7):t\in\Bbb R\big\}\;.$$

Or you can simplify $(1,0,5)+t(2,1,-7)$ to get

$$L=\big\{(1+2t,t,5-7t):t\in\Bbb R\big\}\;.$$

Now just check to see which of your points actually fit this description. Take the point $(0,3,-17)$, for instance: if it’s on $L$, the second coordinate tells you that $t$ must be $3$, but then the first coordinate ought to be $1+2\cdot3=7$. It isn’t, so this point isn’t on $L$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer! :)

Comment: @SusumuMaxYakushijin: You’re very welcome.